# 2008 Server Roles Needed For SharePoint Server 2010

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

If I want to install SharePoint 2010 on a Win 2008 Server, are there any specific server roles that need to be installed? I've read that I may need active directory but I see multiple types of AD. I will provide a list of all the server roles and if someone can tell me which roles to install and why it would be appreciated.

Server Roles:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The one you need is "Active Directory Domain Services". That's the one that provides the real plain directory/domain/user structure.

It is needed if you're creating a all-in-one "development"/"test" virtual machine. However, this means you'll have to create test users in your domain.

Another option is to setup your SharePoint in your current organization domain: you don't install AD on the VM, but you join it to your existing domain (this won't modify anything on your domain; however, SP profile services synchronization may not work correctly since you need a special account to run it; that's the only drawback I' aware of).

Comment: Is the other option you've recommended appropriate if the my server is in a virtual environment (i.e VirtualBox)? For testing purposes I was thinking of installing a sql server along with SharePoint 2010 on a virtual Windows 2008 Server. Is this the right approach?

Comment: For dev/test purposes, yup, I personnaly build a "all-in-one" box (with Virtual Box as well): Active Directory, SQL Server, SharePoint, Office (Office is not recommended on a production server) and Visual Studio (as I'm a developer). This works well, but you need at least ~8GB RAM on your VM.

Comment: Thanks. Can you recommend a tutorial? I was having some issues downloading SharePoint and SQL server onto the Windows Server using IE and for some reason I can't seem to connect to a folder on my PC outside of my VM that has both SQL 2008 and SharePoint Server 2010. This is my first experience with SharePoint so excuse me if it's trivial.

Answer (score 0):

it is not recommended to install the Active directory/ Domain Controller on the SharePoint server, it is not supported in the production.

For sharePoint server you need the following server roles:

- Web Server (IIS) role
- Application Server role including .NET Framework 3.5 SP1

more stuff configured while you run the Pre-requisite installer.
You can read more over here:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288751(v=office.14).aspx

or

http://sharepoint-tutorial.net/post/2009/11/17/installing-sharepoint-server-2010-on-windows-server-2008-r2-and-sql-server-2008-r2-part-1-overview.aspx